# How to assign a value with a condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to assign a value to my variable based on a condition, 
if the id that i receive is equal to any id in an array,

For example i have this:

Array:

```
{
   key: value,
   key: value,
   direccion:[{
    direccionId: 40,
    calle: "string"
   },{
    direccionId: 41,
    calle: "string2"
   }]
}

AgregarInfo(direccionId){
        var infoDireccion = this.editedItem.direccion;            
        console.log(direccionId);
        console.log(infoDireccion.some(direccion => direccion.direccionId === direccionId));
        if(infoDireccion.some(direccion => direccion.direccionId === direccionId)){                
            for(var i = 0; i < infoDireccion.length; i++){
                this.editarCliente.txtCalle = infoDireccion[i].calle;
            }
        }
    }
```

here, if i receive 40, all the values ​​that match id 40 would assign them to variables.

Is what I'm doing right, or is there another way?

Comment: You are overwriting `txtCalle` in each iteration, and you are copying from all the array elements. I think neither is what you want, but to be sure you should include the desired output

Comment: what does `this.editarCliente.txtCalle` represent?

Comment: what do u mean by " all the values ​​that match id 40 would assign them to variables."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in this case rather than `some()` and then looping to find the item. With `find()` you can do both in one step — the condition will be whether `find()` returned anything and the value will be the found item:

```js
let editedItem = {
    key: 'value',
    otherkey: 'value',
    direccion:[{
     direccionId: 40,
     calle: "string"
    },{
     direccionId: 41,
     calle: "string2"
    }]
 }
 
 function AgregarInfo(direccionId){
         var infoDireccion = editedItem.direccion;            
         let found = infoDireccion.find(item => item.direccionId === direccionId)
         let editarCliente = found ? found.calle : undefined
         return editarCliente
} 

console.log(AgregarInfo(40))
console.log(AgregarInfo(41))
console.log(AgregarInfo(42)) // undefined if there's no id 42
```